# Project file must include .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, frameworks

I understand how to fix the error presented in the title of this question, however I am wondering why these are not referenced by *default*. I always add these manually, and frequently forget and get this compile error. Why aren't these references added by Visual Studio upon creation of a new project?

Edit: I am creating class libraries in VS2015 Enterprise.

Comment: You should include the type of project you're creating and the version of visual studio you're using. I've never had to manually add these references.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question.

Comment: Class libraries shouldn't require those assemblies...

Comment: Because not every class library needs those referenced. Those libraries are *mostly* used for GUI tasks, like WPF, image processing, etc. A Class Library isn't necessarily always doing those things.

Comment: Okay I see. I've spent all my time in VS developing libraries that get launched through a separate external framework. Thanks, this makes sense.